# Shell: Save value in a variable, not the command

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'd like to save my current directory into a value.

I do it like this

```
dir=`dirname $0`
```

But when I now change the directory and use this variable, it seems that the expression gets evaluated anew.

Do you know how I can store it's value in the variable, not the expression itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks ok to me. The expression will not get evaluated every time. Try `echo $dir` to see the value of the `dir` variable.

Comment: The expression evaluated to `.`. I've now changed the command to `pwd`.

Comment: What might also be useful sometimes is `readlink -f` - Don't be fooled by the name/man page, it works on files/directories.